# mount_smbfs fails to connect

Tags: swift, macos, mount

I am trying to mount a remote drive to copy few files. I was originally doing this using a shell script. This is working fine and I was able to copy files.

Now I wrote a GUI tool using swift , Inside the mac osx app I load the shell script and run it using Process. The script is loading fine and its receiving the arguments I pass and also it rans. But when it tries to execute this like it errors,

```
mount_smbfs $path ~/buildboxshare/
mount_smbfs $destpath ~/internalsiteshare
```

where path is,

```
//user@ob1-server/Share/ios/DEV/build/Version_4.0.23.0
```

I am getting this error back,

> 2018-11-27 17:12:01.912649+0000 mount_smbfs[60333:30411307]
>    dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 1
>
> 2018-11-27 17:12:02.917815+0000 mount_smbfs[60333:30411307]
>    dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 2
>
> 2018-11-27 17:12:03.920862+0000 mount_smbfs[60333:30411307]
>    dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 3
>
> 2018-11-27 17:12:04.922161+0000 mount_smbfs[60333:30411307]
>    dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect() failed path:/var/run/mDNSResponder Socket:4 Err:-1 Errno:1 Operation not
>    permitted mount_smbfs: server connection failed: No route to host

Comment: Try using an IP address instead of hostname to rule out DNS. Try pre-pending `mount` command with `sudo` to rule out permissions errors.

Comment: The issue has todo with running in Sandbox. When Snadbox option was set to false in XCode it started to connect.